# i can't understand "key=>value" this code in php?

Tags: php

I got a question about the "$key => $value" in the code below... I looked it up in google but it didn't returned any results.. All I know is that "=>" is used in arrays like x = array('a' => 'b').

```
function _stripslashes_rcurs($variable,$top = true)
    {
        $clean_data = array();
        foreach($variable as $key => $value)
        {
            $key = ($top) ? $key : stripslashes($key);
            $clean_data[$key] = (is_aray($value)) ?
                stripslashes_rcurs($value, false) : stripslashes($value);
        }
        return $clean_data;
    }
```

thank you for your help

Comment: thanks for the help guyz I understand it now... I've overlooked some of the basic php concepts... I've been learning php for about 2 days now and tried understanding code snippets in the net... I thought that $key worked as a variable and not as an array... tsk... thanks for the replies

Answer (score 14):

Basically it's looping through `$variable` and setting the key as `$key` and the value as `$value`. So let's say this is your arrray:

```
$variable = array(
  'a' => 'A'
  'b' => 'B'
  'c' => 'C'
);
```

Then in each iteration of the loop, `$key` would be one of the lowercase letters, and `$value` would be the corresponding uppercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

> "$key => $value" ... I looked it up in google but it didn't returned any results

The most important advice for you is to become familiar  with the documentation at www.php.net .  In your case you would look at "foreach" in the "function list".  This documentation is considered by many to be the best example any language has so far.

Answer (score 1):

Key / Value is referring to the index of the array, and the value in said index.
If you have an array like this:

```
$myArray = array("index0","index1","index2");
```

the "foreach" goes through the entire array. The "key" is the current index its on.
So the first time through the loop, the key = 0 and the value = "index0"... next time through, the key = 1 and value = "index1"... get it?

Answer (score 0):

It's just accessing the key and value of the array (all PHP arrays are really dictionaries/hash maps) simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an array.

`$key => $val`

It's for the index and the value of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The your call to (presumably) is_array() function has a small typo.

```
not: is_aray()
but: is_array()
```

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

php.net helped me out more than once :)